# inner product formula of D-dimensional representation of SU(N).

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Take SU(N) group. Consider D-dimensional representation of this group. My question is, **what is the general formula for the inner product for this D-dimensional representation**? Could anyone suggest me a reference to get such general formula.

To clarify my question, let me give an explicit example. Take for example SU(3) group. Consider its 27-dimensional representation. For this 27-plet, the inner product formula is explicitly given in **Eq.(2.40) of this paper**: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0405010.pdf.

In this example, 27-plet is a tensor of two upper and two lower indices. Following this example, now I can ask the question: **what is the inner product formula for a representation of SU(N) that has two upper and two lower indices?**

Comment: Given an orthonormal basis $e_i$ of the representation, then for two vectors $v=\sum_i a_ie_i$ and $w=\sum_i b_ie_i$, we can write $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_ia_i^*b_i$. It is easy to see that any unitary transformation preserves this dot product.

Comment: I agree with your comment. When translating to SU(N), your states represents fundamental rep., for which the inner product is trivial. From the fundamental rep., in principle one can construct higher dimensional reps., and the corresponding inner-product formula. This procedure can be done with some effort for lower dimensional reps (as can be seen in the reference I provided). However, for somewhat higher rep. (D-> large and N-> large), this is a very tedious job. I am sure Mathematicians are cleaver enough to worked out the general expression for inner product for arbitrary reps for SU(N).